# Is there a way to access the camera of a mobile device in Phonegap without actually opening the camera screen?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, camera

I'm attempting to make an app with Phonegap to be used on Android devices and I need a way to take pictures without actually opening the camera screen. I know how to access the camera normally with Phonegap but that involves opening the camera screen, pressing the take picture button and then confirming your picture. I want to be able to directly access the camera and take a picture without having to go to the camera screen and have the user press all those buttons. Is this possible using just html and javascript?

I've looked into getUserMedia and that does exactly what I want but it doesn't work in Phonegap. It only works with certain browsers.

Comment: Its not possible only using HTML & JavaScript. Any how you need some framework to achieve this. Phonegap uses javascript to call its defined methods written in java that handles the camera.